# BeautifulSoup Table Processing

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup, html-table, html-parsing

I'm in a situation where I have to do something a touch hacky. The incoming data is not under my control, so a solution is NOT "just store it more effectively", as much as I'd like that to be the case.

The stuff that I'm getting looks like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Key 1</td>
    <td>Key 2</td>
    <td>Key 3</td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Val 1</td>
    <td>Val 2</td>
    <td>Val 3</td>
    ...
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

and what I want is to cherry-pick certain key/value pairs from certain tables. So, something like

```
{ 'Key 4': 'Val 4', 'Key 32': 'Val 32' ... }
```

I know the appropriate keys ahead of time, but I don't necessarily know where they're positioned, or that every pair of `tr`s represents k/v pairs (`table`s get used for positioning as well as data representation. No, I don't know why.), so the simplest possible solution seems to be `get me the contents of the nth cell of the next row where n is this cells' index`.

What I've got is

```
def findField(soup, fieldName):
    kTd = soup.find(text=fieldName).parent
    ix = len(kTd.findPreviousSiblings('td'))
    valTd = kTd.parent.findNext('tr').findAll('td')[ix]
    return (kTd, valTd)

def fieldsToDict(soup, fieldNames):
    return dict([findField(soup, k) for k in fieldNames])

fieldsToDict(soup, ['Key 4', 'Key 32' ..])
```

but it seems like there must be a more elegant and/or efficient way to express this.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** I'll be more specific, though I may be overthinking this, and this question probably should have been put to codereview.se rather than SO. Two specific things I wanted pointers on from someone who has more Python/BeautifulSoup under their belt than me.

First,

```
...
    ix = len(soup.findPreviousSiblings('td'))
...
```

looks like it could get to be relatively expensive for larger rows. And it seems like the information I'm trying to get can be gotten during the initial parse of the HTML. Is there a built-in method/slot along the lines of `indexAmongPeers`?

Second

```
...
    return dict([findField(soup, k) for k in fieldNames])
```

`dict` in that line seems like it would have to do another traversal of the list coming out of that comprehension. Does that get optimized away in this case? Is there a way to do it in one pass?

Comment: It looks fairly good to me.

Comment: Yeah, what you have seems pretty good already.

Answer (score 0):

I think the looking up is a little bit hard to follow - I'd go for the following:

```
rows = [tr.strings for tr in soup('tr')]
lookup = {k:v for k,v in zip(*rows) if k in {'Key 1', 'Key 2'}}
# {u'Key 1': u'Val 1', u'Key 2': u'Val 2'}
```

Comment: This might work for individual rows, but as I said, not every pair of `tr`s represents k/v pairs (some contain sub-tables and irrelevant information). The snippet I posted was of one particular sub-table present in `soup`, and I don't even want all of it. If the data I was getting used tables only for data representation, then yeah, I'd just `izip` pairwise `tr`s and pull stuff out from there.